# Hooking window creation; hooks not being triggered

Tags: c++, windows, window, hook, dll-injection

Essentially I'm inside a process' memory via an injected DLL and I want to stop window creation. I've tried hooking the following:

- `CreateWindowExW`
- `CreateDialogParamW`
- `DialogBoxParamW`

Unfortunately, the creation of the window I want to destroy is not triggering any of my hooks.  There are several IE controls within the aforementioned window and the CreateWindowExW calls are being hit for them; but not the actual window I want. It's a simple popup box, and does show up in Spy++/Window Hack so I'm certain it's an actual window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the other variations? `CreateWindowExA`, `CreateWindowW`, `CreateWindowA`, ...

Comment: `CreateWindowA/W` are just macros for `CreateWindowExA/W`, and as far as I know all the `*A` functions of the Windows API are just wrappers for the `*W` versions.

Comment: how are you doing the hooking? have you tried a `WH_CBT` hook? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JonathanLingle: Yes and no, the `*A` versions will call the same internal procedure as the `*W` versions, but they don't redirect to the `*W` versions (at least under windows 7).

Comment: @Necrolis thanks for the info, looks like I've been misinformed :)

Comment: @spencercw, my bad, your suggestion actually worked. If you want to post your comment as a solution, I'll upvote & accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try all the possible variations of the functions you are trying to hook `CreateWindowExA`, `CreateWindowW`, `CreateWindowA`, etc. They aren't necessarily just wrappers around the main `*W` one.